# Bitcoin Core make

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling, make

Whenever I try to recompile my changed files in Bitcoin core. I have to run make clean and then make or else it wont compile the changed files. It just goes back to the last compiled file. How do i do smart make where it only compiles the files that I have changed[image]

Comment: Is your system clock wrong perhaps? Alternatively, did you make any changes to the source code and saved them?

Comment: I think my system clock is fine. I also save changes to source code every time but I constantly have to run make clean and then make to see my changes